# How to transfer the numpy.datetime64 to cftime.DatetimeNoLeap

Tags: python-3.x

I want to transfer an array of numpy.datetime64 below into a cftime.DatatimeNoleap format,

```
array(['2022-12-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2022-12-01T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2022-12-01T02:00:00.000000000', ..., '2022-12-31T21:00:00.000000000',
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

```
array([cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(2014, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),
       cftime.DatetimeNoLeap(2014, 12, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),
      dtype=object)
```

The question is there any ways to convert the whole array not one by one?

Thank you.

better with a example.